# Ethernet adapter causing network problems

Tags: networking, ethernet, linux-mint

I have a laptop that when I plug it into a 5-port unmanaged Ethernet switch, it randomly kills the network for all devices connected and its own connection. Here is what I've tried:

- Deleting network profiles on laptop and creating default profile
- Swapping Ethernet cables
- Swapping Ethernet switches (different 5-port switch)
- Giving it a static IP outside the DHCP range within the network range

The laptop has a Realtek Semiconductor RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller rev 12. The problem only shows up when this laptop is on the network and it isn't consistent (may work fine for an hour or day). The only thing consistent is it always takes a long time to initially connect compared to the other devices.

Any ideas on ways to further troubleshoot this issue before buying another network card?

Comment: Computers generally don't have *replaceable* network cards nowadays: the circuitry is built into the motherboard. Have you tried booting it into a different OS, for example you can get Linux to run off a DVD or USB drive, to make sure that it is not malware on the laptop which is interfering with the network?

Comment: When you say "initially connect" - you mean to get a DHCP IP?

Comment: What's running on the laptop - maybe you have something running which is causing a broadcast storm?  If you have a USB ethernet adapter do you get the same problem with it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried a different OS on your comment. I was using Linux mint and tried PopsOS live cd (since founding company also built the laptop) and it connected in under 3 seconds. Fastest ever. I'm continuing to test with all other devices on the switch.

Comment: @MrR, yes i meant the point it gets an IP. The only thing running on the laptop is also running on my desktop without issues. They both have the same OS, same amount of RAM, CPU and storage. The only difference is the desktop is a different manufacture. I don't have a USB ethernet adapter. I will purchase one since I need one on hand.

Comment: @learnsomemore Oh, hang on... do you mean your laptop has Mint installed and that has the problem?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes it has Linux Mint on it and the problem appears to be with the OS drivers. When purchasing it a while back from system76, they said that it should work fine as long as i installed the system76 drivers which i did but bluetooth and ethernet never worked very well on it.

Comment: @learnsomemore Hmmm... do you think you might like Pop!_OS as your new OS if System76 can't supply working drivers for Mint?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Pop!_OS is interesting. But I'm more preoccupied with improving how efficiently I get work done than trying different OSs. Every time I change OS's I loose a little productivity during the process of learning its shortcuts, quirks, etc. I'd rather see more laptops built with hardware and drivers that natively support the Linux kernel and many major Linux distors than trying out another OS.